# Mail Enabled Public Folders routing to offline server Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, public-folders

Exchange 2010 Databases with replicas.
The hubs keep trying to deliver to offline server.

Things Ive tried:
Applied Rollup that supposedly allowed for Smartrouting 
Mail Disabled then Re enabled

Both solved the issue but temporarily, then reverted back to reattempting the bad DB. I'm contemplating removing the PFDB from Exchange since it's offline anyway. Then the question is the deletion process for that so that it doesnt touch the replicas on the live servers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove that offline server correctly.

Exchange will always try to use all servers, even ones that are offline. That is how it is designed to work.

Manually removing the server is not a supported action, you either need to start the server up so it can be removed correctly, or if not possible do a recover server installation of Exchange on to a VM and then remove that recovered installation.

Have you removed the server from the list of replicas? If not you should do that. However it will not stop transport from trying to use that other server. Exchange doesn't "know" that it is offline - for the same reason the "turn off and see what breaks" method doesn't work during migrations.

Comment: After removing the server from replicas, since I couldn't resurrect the server (yet) I opted to remove the PFDB via ADSI. It's been 72 hours so far so good.